# "R" is not recogonized as an internal or external command

Tags: r, package

we have used the following code snippet to create the R package

```
setwd("C:/Users/myname/Desktop/TestPackage")
getwd()
require(stats)
add<-function(x,y)x+y
package.skeleton(list=c("add"),name="addpkg")
```

while  build this package in cmd using the following command

```
C:Users\myname\Desktop\TestPackage> R CMD build addpkg
```

I got the following error

"R" is not recogonized  as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

```
NOTE

System Directory for R :> C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2
System Directory for R Studio:>C:\Program Files\RStudio
System Directory for R tools :>C:\Rtools
```

Operating System : Windows -8

Path in Environment variables:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS      Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files(x86)\R-3.0.2\bin\;C:\Program Files(x86)\R-3.0.2\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\RStudio\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\RStudio\bin\x64\;C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin32;C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin64;
```

Comment: Your R path is `C:\Program Files\R-3.0.2` but your path variable contains `C:\Program Files(x86)\R-3.0.2\bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use, C:\Program Files\R-3.0.2 
Instead of C:\Program Files(86)\R-3.0.2